# Nested navigation in jetpack compose reusing screens in different navigation graphs

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The problem is this: I have a profile screen and I can access it from the bottom navigation bar (I also have a nested navigation) (bottom navigation bar: profile, home and search)
and I can also go to the same profile from the search (only the profile will be of a different person), but when I go from the search, my bottom bar switches to the profile icon and does not remain in the search

this code :

```
NavigationBar(
        modifier = Modifier,
        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
    ) {

        items.forEachIndexed { _, item ->

            val selected = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.hierarchy?.any {
                it.route == item.route
            } ?: false

            NavigationBarItem(
                selected = selected,
                onClick = {
                    if (!selected) {
                        navigationState.navigateIn(item.route ?: "")
                    }
                },
                icon = {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector =
                        if (selected) {
                            item.selectedIcon
                        } else {
                            item.unselectedIcon
                        },
                        contentDescription = null,
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

I can fix this with different screens for my profile and other people's profiles, but when other screens are added, I will have to make copies of the screens, so I'm not sure if this is a good solution

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot that clearly describes your issue?

Comment: @Yannick I want to go from the search screen to the profile screen of another person and it takes me to the profile graph (my profile) (since I already have a profile screen in the bottom navigation and the bottom navigation switches), does this mean that I will need to create a separate view and add it to the search graph to remain in the graph or you can somehow reuse the screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good to create a new one. And create one common composable function for both screens and call in both screens. As you can see in the Instagram app they also do this thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really separated the ProfileView function and call it from different screens passing different state, tell me if the sources of popular applications are publicly available, you said that Instagram does this

Comment: I don't know of any publicly available demo.  you can achieve this think by as I said earlier creating separate screens like Instagram.

Comment: @Alexey It's work ??

Comment: It's my project

Comment: no, i am telling you. my suggestion is work or not?

Comment: haha, yep this work, I'm upset because I will have many screens inside my profile and they will also have to be separated, what can I do, thanks